# Is it possible to create a decompiler using AI?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, reference-request

I would like to decompile a compiled file to source code.

Is it possible to use any AI technique to perform decompilation? Is there any research on this topic? If yes, can you briefly explain one of the existing approaches (just to get some insight)? I would also appreciate links to research papers on this topic.

Comment: [Here](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/205/2444) you have a similar question.